# Euler central differences method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0,$$ $$y = cos(x), t=0,$$$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=csin(x), t=0  $$

has a solution $$y=cos(x−ct).$$

I wanted to expand both the derivatives as centered differences. So, in order to expand my derivatives, I did as shown below;

$$\frac{y(i+1) - y(i-1)}{2Δt} +c(\frac{y(i+1) - y(i-1)}{2Δx}) = 0$$

$$\frac{y}{Δt} +c(\frac{y}{Δx})= 0$$

Now, I also intend to prove that the algebraic solution is an exact solution of the difference formula if I choose $Δx=cΔt$. How do I achieve this goal?

Comment: Please show us your attempts. Did you try representing $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ as $\frac{y^{n+1}_i - y^{n-1}_i}{2 \Delta t}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ as $\frac{y^n_{i+1} - y^n_{i-1}}{2 \Delta x}$? While discretization has its problems that can be discussed, you should present your work.

Comment: @Mathemagical I just showed my work. Can you please help now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:
Your time-discretization in your update to your post is not right.  Please note how I have indicated it in the comment above - there are 2 indices, one (subscript i) indicates the x dimension and the other (superscript n) indicates the time dimension.  Your teacher should have taught you this.  Anyway, look at equation 29 on this [linked doc](http://civil.utah.edu/~bartlett/CVEEN6920/FDM_basics.pdf). For this problem, you don't even need to think about indexes, just that you are representing $\frac{\partial y(t,x)}{ \partial x}$ as $\frac{y(t, x+\Delta x)-y(t, x-\Delta x)}{2 \Delta x}$.  Similarly for $\frac{\partial y(t,x)}{ \partial t}$ in terms of $\Delta t$

Now, to show the $y=\cos(x-ct)$ satisfies the equation when the "grid speed" $\frac{\Delta x}{ \Delta t}$ equals the wave speed $c$, just plug in $y=\cos(x-ct)$ into the discretized equation you just created.

You will need the trigonometric identity
$$\cos(x)−\cos(y)=−2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})$$

And indeed, when grid speed equals wave speed, the LHS of the discretized equation, then evaluates to zero, which is the RHS.